# How to read a text file and check against its contents with python

Tags: python, string, text, variable-assignment

I am attempting to read a text file, print its contents, and stop when it reaches the "flag".

My code is:

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append("/Libraries/Documents")
 file = open("readmepython.txt", "r")
 while True:
     x = file.readline()
     if x != "break":
         print(x)
     else:
         break

 #doesnt work
```

The text file in question has only this inside of it with no extra spaces or returns:

```
this is the ip
this is the /24
this is the gateway
this is the name server
break
```

The loop will continue to run infinitely, and I am unsure how to properly assign the variable so that it checks properly.

Does python not assign the raw string value when reading from a text file? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `print(repr(x))` after the readline and you will see the problem for yourself.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just writing the loop to end when you are finished reading the file? i.e. `For line in file: print line` ...

Comment: That explains the issue with my text file. I should have realized that there were return characters present. Thank you @MarkTolonen

Comment: @Mark_Eng I am practicing skills I will need for an upcoming project I want to undertake. Checking for errors in a text document will be necessary. You are correct that just reading the whole file would be much, much easier :)

Comment: fyi, `file.readlines()` will give you the whole file in one shot.  if you are dealing with small files, this might be something worth using (larger files might use up too much resources on your system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Libraries/Documents")
file = open("readmepython.txt", "r")
while True:
    x = file.readline().strip()
    if x != "break":
      print(x)
    else:
      break
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like,

```
file = open("readmepython.txt", "r")
For line in file:
   print line
```

or

```
file = open("readmepython.txt", "r")
For line in file.readlines():
    print line
```

see also:[python looping through input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726349/python-looping-through-input-file)

Answer (score 0):

While many of the answers were extremely helpful for other issues I had, none explicitly answered the question. 
<strike>I have used [Mr.Mean's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37792721/4703192) suggestion of .replace to clear up the hidden characters that are returned in text documents.</strike> [Another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469072/joel-goldstick) showed me .strip() (something I should have known), which works much better to *strip* away the hidden characters.

When reading from a text document in Python, if one pressed enter for a new line there will be an unseen

```
\n
```

at the end of the string, which will be enclosed with single quotes ' '.

I ended up using the .replace methode twice to clear the string into what I wanted. This could have also been done by slicing the first character, and last three characters of the string.

My new, functional code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Libraries/Documents")
file = open("readmepython.txt", "r")
while True:
    x = file.readline().strip
    if x != "break":
      print(x)
    else:
      break

#does work
```

I will end up accepting this answer unless someone suggests otherwise.

Comment: You can also use x.strip() to strip all whitespace at start and end of the string https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip  So, in your case: `x = file.readline().strip()`

Comment: Awesome! That is much more simple. @joelgoldstick

Comment: @joelgoldstick If you would like to answer I would gladly accept that answer