# Python the total sales price from a text file

Tags: python

I would like to subtract two numbers that are written in my text file.I have to calculate the total sales in each line by doing sales - cost price.

the text file contains:

```
200 123
300 189
111 77
```

I would like to subtract these values to get the output. Each line gives a different sales profit.

Comment: Can you please clarify the expected result ?

Comment: Helpful post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726349/python-looping-through-input-file.  Once you read in the lines, split based on spaces, convert from string to integer then do the subtraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```py
input_file = open('input.txt', 'r')

sales_profits = []
for line in input_file:
  sales, cost = map(int, line.split(" "))
  sales_profits.append(sales - cost)

print(sales_profits) # Your result is there - do what you want with :)
```